# Problem deploying a NEXT JS application on my CPANEL

Tags: node.js, next.js, server, backend, cpanel

I just started Node dveleppemnt. In order to pratice, i create a NextJS application. My problem is when i try to deploy it on my CPANEL, it don't work. I try to soled using google search but i don't have solution

This this error found when i try to run

```
num run start // => IN PACKAGE.JSON FILE  "start": "NODE_ENV=production node server.js"
```

## Error :

returncode: 1
stdout:

> next-app@0.1.0 dev /home/user/nodejs/nextapp
> next dev
> stderr:

- warn You are using a non-standard "NODE_ENV" value in your environment. This creates inconsistencies in the project and is strongly advised ...

if (typeof fetch === "undefined" && typeof globalThis.fetch === "undefined") {
^

## ReferenceError: globalThis is not defined
at Object. (/home/bmog6953/nodevenv/sites/nodejs/nextapp/10/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/node-polyfill-fetch.js:4:44)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)...

On my website, i have this message

> It works!
> NodeJS 10.24.1

I need your help to solve this problem.
thank you again !

I changed package.json file
I try to search solution on Google and web forums
I also write a message to cpanel administrators for help